# SQL Update подставить поле из другой таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

Как сделать UPDATE поля где id = 1 вставив в одно из полей значение из 2 таблицы где id = 5

Comment: в большинстве СУБД работает синтаксис `update table set поле=(select поле from table2 where id=5) where id=1`

Comment: Visual Studio error: Operation must use an updatable query

Comment: "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1, table2 
set table1.поле = table2.поле
where table1.id=1 and table2.id=5;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Не за что. Плюс 5 символов.