# Как написать Update запрос для одной таблицы на основе данных другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Есть две таблицы:
1. DEPT (DEPT.ID, DEPT.NAME)
2. UDFEMP (С кучей столбцов, одно из них UDFEMP.DEPT равняется DEPT.ID таблицы DEPT).

в DatGridView я вывожу данные запросом, через INNER JOIN заменяя UDFEMP.DEPT на соответствующее имя из DEPT.NAME.

По кнопке нужно сделать update в базе, изменив название одной организации на другую, выбирая название из Combobox, но при этом чтобы в UDFEMP.DEPT записался DEPT.ID соответствующий новому названию.

Пробую такой запрос:

```
UPDATE udfemp SET udfemp.dept = dept.name FROM udfemp INNER JOIN DEPT ON udfemp.dept = dept.id WHERE UDFEMP.ID = '32300'
```

Получаю ошибку: **Ошибка преобразования значения nvarchar "СТО" в тип данных int.**

Подскажите, как переписать запрос для моей ситуации? Не могу сообразить нужный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот таким запросом:

```
UPDATE udfemp SET udfemp.dept =( select dept.id from dept where dept.name = @DEPTNAME) where udfemp.id = @EMPID
```

Помогла вот эта статья: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753133/sql-update-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B?rq=1)